# Font resizer with javascript not work

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create font resizer for user.I can do with box using "this".But I  could not with button.How I can do that ? I'm using with class not id(if I use like #keko then it's work)

```css
.keko {
    position: relative;
    width:70px;
 height:70px;
    margin: auto;
 font-size: 15px;
    background: green;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Label.css%20-%20Label%20every%20thing!_dosyalar/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Label.css%20-%20Label%20every%20thing!_dosyalar/label.css">
     
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".keko").click(function(){
            $(this).css("font-size", "50px");
        });    
    }); 
    </script>
                  
 <div class="keko"><p>This text</p><div>
 <button type="button">Add CSS Styles</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the corresponding selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(".keko").css("font-size", "50px");
  });
});
```

```css
.keko {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="keko">
  <p>This text</p>
<div>

<button type="button">Add CSS Styles</button>
```

Comment: Thank you.So do you have any idea how it incrase "  font-size", +"1px" or something.What should I use.

Comment: `$(".keko").css("font-size", parseInt($(".keko").css("font-size")) + 1);`

Comment: @KucuKeko, happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me as long as I close the head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
    .keko {
        position: relative;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: 15px;
        background: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".keko").click(function(){
                $(this).css("font-size", "50px");
            });    
        }); 
    </script>

    <div class="keko"><p>This text</p><div>
    <button type="button">Add CSS Styles</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a lot of ways to go about it. You could put it on the html page as shown. I usually try to keep my js in separate files and refer with a script tag. The only important thing is that you load jquery first (if you are going to use jquery, this could be handled with vanilla js as well)